# How to write this type of L in equation latex

Tags: math-mode, fonts

How I can use this style of L in math mode?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like a normal sans serif L, so

```
\mathsf{L}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\mathsf{L}(\mathbf{z},\mathbf{x})$
\end{document}
```